# how to send parameters from javascript to html form

Tags: javascript, html

i have spend great time in searching this type of problem but found no suitable answer. what i am trying is to get text name `<input type='text' name="qname">` from java script and send in html form. is there is a possibilty? my stress is on this part.
code:

```
<html>
<!-- skipped part-->
 <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    function create()
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divId = "someId";
        newDiv.id = divId;
        var output = "<table id='e' border><tr><td><input type='text' name="qname"></td><td><input type='text1' name="qty"></td><td><input type='text' name="price"></td><button onclick=del('"+ divId +"')>delete</button></td></tr></table>";
        newDiv.innerHTML = output;
        newDiv.className = 'newClass';
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);                          
    }


    function del (id) {
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }


    </script>


<body>
    <form method="post" action="transaction.php" onclick="create()">    
    <button onclick="create()">create</button>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can see that you have improperly quoted string where you are setting `var output = "<table ..."`  I would suggest single quotes around the entire string (except where concatenation is performed) and double quotes for each of the HTML properties.

Comment: Two problems. 1) You need to escape those quotes: `name=\"qname\"`. 2) You need to append to the form, not the body, if you want it to post: `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].appendChild(newDiv);`

Comment: i need to do is to write on div and send to html form.

Comment: even it sends one whole div it would be more better but i just want to send parameter of row to html.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].appendChild(newDiv); where shoul i write this. iside javascript function or outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You append the new HTML to the body instead of to the form. Give the form an id, e.g.

```
<form method="post" action="transaction.php" onclick="create()" id="myform">
```

and then append the input to the form with:

```
document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: i understand the forum shell i place the document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(newDiv); before function end barackets?

Comment: not happening. and also can i place the whole row in database?

Comment: what do you mean by "not happening"? and what database?

Comment: when i placed document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(newDiv); before bracket end and run the page and selected on create button it does nothing. and as u see 4 input types in javascript is it possible to send the whole row to database through forum id??

Comment: You did escape the quotes, right? Now, since nothing is happening, probably the error console will tell you something useful...

Comment: i did but still not. tired now.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `output` variable string formed improperly.

If you check the console, you'll see:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Try formatting your string like this:

```
var output = "<table id='e' border><tr><td><input type='text' name='qname'></td><td><input type='text1' name='qty'></td><td><input type='text' name='price'></td><button onclick=del('" + divId + "')>delete</button></td></tr></table>";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Lcnet/

Comment: Alternatively, escape those quotes: `"<table id=\"e\" border` etc